# Get variable from javascript into controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I need to have a variable from an java script function into my controller.
Here you can see my ajax function

```
<script>
    $('#spielAuswahl').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var spielID = e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $.get('/spieler?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my web router

```
Route::get('/spieler', 'SpielerController@getSpieler');
```

And here my controller function

```
public function getSpieler(){
        $spielID = Input::get(spielID);
        echo $spielID;
    }
```

I have this issue

> jquery.js:9664 GET http://localhost:8000/spieler?spielID=3 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

What I have to change?

Comment: please check the preview of error

Comment: Make sure error reporting is turned on and open that url to see why. Or check the error logs. Suggest you read docs for `Input::get()`

Comment: first can you tell us which framework is this? so that we can suggest you the  solution.. is this laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exatly want to do, but here is a solution to pass a value.

You can name your routes, example:

```
Route::post('/spieler', ['as' => 'spieler', 'uses' => 'SpielerController@getSpieler']);
```

Your jquery:

```
var token = "{{ Session::token() }}";

$('#spielAuswahl').on('change', function(e){
  console.log(e);

  var spielID = e.target.value;

  $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "{{ route('spieler') }}",
     data: {id: spielID, _token: token}
  });
}
```

Finally your controller:

```
public function getSpieler(Request $request) {
   $id = $request['id'];
   echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown is missing some quotes:

```
public function getSpieler(){
    $spielID = Input::get('spielID');  // quote `spielID` here
    echo $spielID;
}
```

If you're using Laravel 5, you can use the request:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function getSpieler(Request $request) {
    echo $request->spielID;
}
```

You can find out more more details about your `500 Server Error` in the web server logs, and `storage/logs/laravel.log`.